# Custom TextView in Button

Tags: android, button, textview

I have created one custom textview class. Through this class, i can set the fonts, set innershadow of the text, set outershadow of the text, set the radius and color of the text.I want to use these characteristics of textviews in the text present in button as well. I have researched through google but i have not been able to find that solution which solves my problem. So, if anybody has any ideas on this topic, then you will be of a great help.

Properties that i define in my textview are

```
    xmlns:braindigit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.MyCustomTextView" //this is in the main layout        

   <com.example.MyCustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/stateInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/you_are_not_logged_in"
        android:textColor="#3191d2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        braindigit:innerShadowColor="#003456"
        braindigit:innerShadowDy="1"
        braindigit:innerShadowRadius="1"
        braindigit:outerShadowColor="#ffffff"
        braindigit:outerShadowDy="1"
        braindigit:outerShadowRadius="1" />
```

Theres no problem with the custom textview.But, i dont know how can i use these custom textvalues for my button.

Comment: Post some code or what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have posted the codes in my edit @Dipak Keshariya

Comment: It is too hard to find solution of your question, make one image and set this image as a background of button.

Comment: my main problem is, i want to use the features of textview in the text of button as well. @DipakKeshariya i dont think image will solve my problem.........

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your custom class extends TextView, you can just use the same implementation and extend Button.  Button inherits from TextView.

Comment: Do you mean that i create on Custom Button class that extends the given CUSTOM TEXT VIEW

Comment: No, you can just copy your code over, rename the class and have it extend Button instead of TextView